# Is creating object through parameter of "add" method acceptable in java?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner and want to create a map in java that is made up of some tiles.
I need to create and keep some objects in each tile.My code is as follows:

```
LinkedList itemList = new LinkedList();    
itemList.add(new BigArrow());
```

Does it keep an instance of the BigArrow class in itemList?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's a perfectly acceptable way to do it, although you have to specity what object your `LiskedList` is holding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly fine and is a *good* coding style.

Under the hood, the reference count of your *anonymous temporary* `BigArrow` instance will be incremented when it is attached to the `itemList` container. So yes, the instance will stay alive for as long as the container.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it keep an instance of the BigArrow class in itemList?

Yes, as far as the `itemList` is live or you don't clear the list content, that instance will be there

Answer (score 2):

```
yes..but it `itemList.add(new BigArrow());` create the BigArrow object
```

and its reference is assign to it, you can read in this format its more readable and understandable.

```
   LinkedList itemList = new LinkedList();    
    BigArrow ba=new BigArrow();
    itemList.add(ba);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is acceptable to create it like that provided you specify what object the LiskedList  is having. Also the the instance will stay alive for as long as the container until and unless you clear the list.